# A close form for a Fourier transform

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

Is there a close form for the Fourier transform of $F(x)=H(x)\text{sech} (x)$, $H=\mathbf 1_{\mathbb R_+}$ ? Or is it easy to determine the range of $\hat F$?

Comment: 1/cosh (btw, I don't think notation sech is to be employed) is (up to a rescaling) its own Fourier transform. The fact that you multiply it by Heaviside changes things a lot...

Comment: @JeanMarie. The multiplication with $H$ will make the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sech}$ be convoluted with $\hat{H}$. That might however be difficult to calculate.

Comment: Write $\operatorname {sech} x$ as a sum of exponentials and integrate termwise. You'll get  the Lerch transcendent.